# compilation terminated error showing while building ndk

Tags: android, build, makefile, android-ndk, native-code

I am new to android NDK. I am using android studio.I followd the steps in [Building NDK apps with Android studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ). I created the c file with a native method and works fine. But after adding make files and build using ndk-build ,I am getting the following error.

> E:\Projects\NDKProjects\MyNDKSample\app\src\main>E:\ndk\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd
>   [armeabi] Compile thumb  : HelloJNI <= HelloJNI.c
>   jni/HelloJNI.c:16:1: fatal error: opening dependency file ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/HelloJNI/HelloJNI.o.d: No such file or directory
>    }
>    ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/HelloJNI/HelloJNI.o] Error 1

This is my MytestCode class,

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_anu_myndksample_MainActivity_HelloJNI  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hello from JNI");
```

}

What might be the error?

Gradle version:2.4
(classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0')
Studio Version=1.3.2

Comment: Which version of Android Studio and Gradle do you use?

Comment: In new versions of Android Studio, you don't have to specify makefiles or run `ndk-build` - just add C/C++ code to your Gradle files. I have a larger example at https://github.com/kneth/AndroidCalcPi.

Comment: @geisshirt what about using external libraries?

Comment: External libraries with Gradle can be a bit cumbersome. If you compile the library yourself, you will probably have to create a static library and link with your JNI stuff.

Comment: By the way, if you by external library mean system libraries which are not part of NDK, you can manually load the `.so` file. See https://github.com/kneth/AndroidCalcPi/blob/non-ndk-libraries/app/src/main/jni/net_zigzak_androidcalcpi_NativeEncrypt.cpp as an example.